# Got runUntilCurrent Error Message when running Scrapy Spider with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, yield

I'm a beginner in Scrapy. I want to collect links of items in the index page and get the information from the item pages. Because I need to deal with the javascript on the index page, I use selenium webdriver with scrapy. Here's my code in progress.py .

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from mustdo.items import MustdoItem
import time

class ProgressSpider(Spider):
    name = 'progress' # spider's name
    allowed_domains = ['example.com'] # crawling domain
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com'] 

def __init__(self):
    Spider.__init__(self)
    self.log('----------in __init__----------')
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def parse(self, response):
    self.log('----------in parse----------')
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    # Here're some operations of self.driver with javascript.
    elements = []
    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td/a[1]')
    #get the number of the item
    self.log('----------Link number is----------'+str(len(elements))) 
    for element in elements:
        #get the url of the item
        href = element.get_attribute('href')
        print href
        self.log('----------next href is ----------'+href)
        yield Request(href,callback=self.parse_item)
    self.driver.close()

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log('----------in parse_item----------')
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    #build item
    item = MustdoItem()
    item['title'] = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2').text
    self.log('----------item created----------'+self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2').text)
    time.sleep(10)
    return item
```

Also, I have items.py defining the MustdoItem used here. Here's the code.

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class MustdoItem(Item):
    title = Field()
```

When I run the spider, I can get several items (probably 6 to 7 out of 20). But after a while, I get error messages as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 82
      4, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 63
      8, in _tick
        taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\task.py", line 48
      4, in _oneWorkUnit
        result = next(self._iterator)
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\uti
      ls\defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
        work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\uti
      ls\defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
        yield next(it)
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
      trib\spidermiddleware\offsite.py", line 23, in process_spider_output
        for x in result:
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
      trib\spidermiddleware\referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
        return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
      trib\spidermiddleware\urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy-0.22.2-py2.7.egg\scrapy\con
      trib\spidermiddleware\depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
      File "mustdo\spiders\progress.py", line 32, in parse
        print element.tag_name
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webeleme
      nt.py", line 50, in tag_name
        return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TAG_NAME)['value']
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webeleme
      nt.py", line 369, in _execute
        return self._parent.execute(command, params)
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdrive
      r.py", line 164, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "F:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhan
      dler.py", line 164, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: u'El
    ement not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked
    up' ; Stacktrace:
        at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web_elem
    ent_cache.js:7610)
        at Utils.getElementAt (file:///c:/users/marian/appdata/local/temp/tm
    pmgnqid/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7210)

        at WebElement.getElementTagName (file:///c:/users/marian/appdata/loc
    al/temp/tmpmgnqid/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processo
    r.js:10353)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/mar
    ian/appdata/local/temp/tmpmgnqid/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/c
    ommand_processor.js:10878)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/maria
    n/appdata/local/temp/tmpmgnqid/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/com
    mand_processor.js:10883)
        at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/marian/appda
    ta/local/temp/tmpmgnqid/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_pr
    ocessor.js:10825)
```

I've tested my codes and found out that if I removed "yield Request(href,callback=self.parse_item)" in parse function, I could get all the links of items. And when "progress.py" was running, I observed that after the first print of "----------in parse_item----------" in self.log, the error messages came out. With my inference, yield sequence results in the error. But I don't know how to deal with this problem.

Any insight is appreciated!

Best regards! :)

Comment: May be the page is dynamically updated. Try to pass the html code of the page to the Selector: `sel = Selector(self.driver.page_source)`. After use the same xpath to extract the links.